# Replace markdown with html in wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, oop, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace all the wiki markdown text from my custom post. Example:

```
== My Subheading == 
=== My sub Subheading ===
==== another heading ====
```

I am trying to change that content like below:

> ### My Subheading
>
> #### My sub Subheading
>
> another
> heading

So, I tried to use below function. But, didn't worked!

I am seeing:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "{", expecting "("
```

I am not much familiar with WP custom function. Can u guys please help me?

```
function the_content{
    private $patterns, $replacements;

    public function __construct($analyze=false) {
        $this->patterns=array(
            "/\r\n/",
            
            // Headings
            "/^==== (.+?) ====$/m", 
            "/^=== (.+?) ===$/m",               
            "/^== (.+?) ==$/m",                 
    
            // Formatting
            "/\'\'\'\'\'(.+?)\'\'\'\'\'/s",                 
            "/\'\'\'(.+?)\'\'\'/s",                     
            "/\'\'(.+?)\'\'/s",                 
    
            // Special
            "/^----+(\s*)$/m",                  
            "/\[\[(file|img):((ht|f)tp(s?):\/\/(.+?))( (.+))*\]\]/i",   
            "/\[((news|(ht|f)tp(s?)|irc):\/\/(.+?))( (.+))\]/i",        
            "/\[((news|(ht|f)tp(s?)|irc):\/\/(.+?))\]/i",           
    
            // Indentations
            "/[\n\r]: *.+([\n\r]:+.+)*/",                   
            "/^:(?!:) *(.+)$/m",                    
            "/([\n\r]:: *.+)+/",                        
            "/^:: *(.+)$/m",                        
    
            // Ordered list
            "/[\n\r]?#.+([\n|\r]#.+)+/",                    
            "/[\n\r]#(?!#) *(.+)(([\n\r]#{2,}.+)+)/",           
    
            // Unordered list
            "/[\n\r]?\*.+([\n|\r]\*.+)+/",                  
            "/[\n\r]\*(?!\*) *(.+)(([\n\r]\*{2,}.+)+)/",                
    
            // List items
            "/^[#\*]+ *(.+)$/m",                        
    
            "/^(?!<li|dd).+(?=(<a|strong|em|img)).+$/mi",           
            "/^[^><\n\r]+$/m",                      
        );
        $this->replacements=array(
            "\n",
            
            // Headings
            "<h3>$1</h3>",
            "<h2>$1</h2>",
            "<h1>$1</h1>",
    
            //Formatting
            "<strong><em>$1</em></strong>",
            "<strong>$1</strong>",
            "<em>$1</em>",
    
            // Special
            "<hr/>",
            "<img src=\"$2\" alt=\"$6\"/>",
            "<a href=\"$1\">$7</a>",
            "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>",
    
            // Indentations
            "\n<dl>$0\n</dl>",
            "<dd>$1</dd>",
            "\n<dd><dl>$0\n</dl></dd>",
            "<dd>$1</dd>",
    
            // Ordered list
            "\n<ol>\n$0\n</ol>",
            "\n<li>$1\n<ol>$2\n</ol>\n</li>",
    
            // Unordered list
            "\n<ul>\n$0\n</ul>",
            "\n<li>$1\n<ul>$2\n</ul>\n</li>",
    
            // List items
            "<li>$1</li>",
    
            // Newlines
            "$0<br/>",
            "$0<br/>",
        );
        if($analyze) {
            foreach($this->patterns as $k=>$v) {
                $this->patterns[$k].="S";
            }
        }
    }
    public function parse($input) {
        if(!empty($input))
            $output=preg_replace($this->patterns,$this->replacements,$input);
        else
            $output=false;
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Mainly I am trying to use a filter on the_content, which will convert markdown text to simple HTML using regex replace.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues.

1. You weren't declaring your class properly (it is not a "function").
2. There was trailing space after `== My Subheading ==` (before the end of line marker -- you need to allow zero or more spaces before `$`)

Please educate yourself on [PHP's PSR-12 coding standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) -- this will help you to write clean, consistent, and professional code.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iuUa4))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
== My Subheading == 
=== My sub Subheading ===
==== another heading ====
TEXT;

class ContentParser
{
    private $patterns = [];
    private $replacements = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->patterns = [
            // Headings
            "/^==== (.+?) ====\h*$/m",
            "/^=== (.+?) ===\h*$/m",
            "/^== (.+?) ==\h*$/m",
        ];
        $this->replacements = [
            // Headings
            "<h3>$1</h3>",
            "<h2>$1</h2>",
            "<h1>$1</h1>",
        ];
    }
    public function parse($input) {
        if (!empty($input)) {
            $output = preg_replace($this->patterns, $this->replacements, $input);
        } else {
            $output = false;  // I don't recommend returning a boolean when otherwise returning strings
        }
        return $output;
    }
}

$object = new ContentParser();
var_export($object->parse($text));
```

Output: (the single quotes are from `var_export()`, you can use `echo` instead)

```
'<h1>My Subheading</h1>
<h2>My sub Subheading</h2>
<h3>another heading</h3>'
```